How to delete rows in an xarray containing a certain value of date?
I have an xarray containing data from an NetCDF4 data file.
This xarray has a time dimension where several rows probably contain missing data. Their time stamp is always '1904-01-01T00:00:00.000000'. But no specific NAN values. Also the other data columns have different than NAN unvalid values.
How can I delete these total rows anyhow?
The time dimension of the xarray looks like:
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 5760)>
array(['2018-02-21T00:00:04.000000000', 
       '2018-02-21T00:00:19.000000000',
       '1904-01-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-02-21T00:00:34.000000000', 
        ..., 
       '2018-02-21T23:59:52.000000000', 
       '1904-01-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1904-01-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-02-21T23:59:58.000000000',
       '1904-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')

Aimed look is like:
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 5760)>
array(['2018-02-21T00:00:04.000000000', 
       '2018-02-21T00:00:19.000000000',
       '2018-02-21T00:00:34.000000000', 
        ..., 
       '2018-02-21T23:59:52.000000000', 
       '2018-02-21T23:59:58.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')

The xarray computation guide doesn't help me in that case.
dropna won't work as there is not really any NANs.
Then
I tried with
DS = DS[DS.time != '2020-01-01T00:00:00']and  DS = DS.where(DS.time > '2020-01-01T00:00:00') but that all wouldn't work on xarrays.
How is the correct way handling that problem?

store the 1904-01-01T00:00:00.000000 value in a variable find all the values of date['time'] for that variable store it some whare and then validate the whole ds['time'] with DS.where
# DS = xr.open_dataset('your_file')

# Identify rows with the invalid time stamp
invalid_time = '1904-01-01T00:00:00.000000'
invalid_rows = DS['time'] == invalid_time

# Invert the boolean mask to select rows that do not match the invalid time stamp
valid_ds = DS.where(~invalid_rows, drop=True)

something like this would work I believe.
here is a link for xarray.where

thank you for your answer. The thought is good and I played around with it. Hence, this is not working for dataset. The unvalid rows still remain in valid_ds. Comparing dimensions the total dataset contain 5670 rows. If I select all unvalid times with unvalid_time = DS.sel(time='1904-01-01T00:00:00.000000000') and print(unvalid_time) the dimension is 5067. but even this selection I can't somehow apply to the original dataset.
